# How to reproduce `git push -u` behavior, that is, auto-set local branch as the new remote or push branch?

Tags: magit

No matter how I fiddle with magit options, I cannot reproduce the following behavior:

- I checkout `origin/master`.
- I create a *new* `feature-branch` on top of it; its name is unique.
- I make changes, add commits to that branch.
- I push the branch, and it ends up as `origin/feature-branch`.

This behavior is trivially achieved by `git push -u`.

From within magit, the "Push" popup suggests to set upstream, but it suggests `master`, or other *existing* upstream branches.

I want my local name branch be settable as upstream, *or* the push remote branch, without copy-pasting.

An elisp snippet to set the upstream branch would be equally helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of pushing to the upstream using <kbd>P u</kbd>, use <kbd>P p</kbd> to push to the "push target".

Its useful to treat `origin/master` (or `master`) as "the" other branch related to `feature-branch`. Its equally useful to treat `origin/feature-branch` (or `fork/feature-branch`) as the other branch.

Luckily you don't have to choose, because Git supports associating **two** distinct other branches with the current branch. The "upstream" and the "push-target branch" (the branch by the same name as the local branch on the push-remote).

This is explained in more detail in [The Two Remotes](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/The-Two-Remotes.html).

Comment: It's good to know! But I still cannot have my current local branch name _automatically inserted_ into the `Pp` list or into the `bC` list, or any auto-completions therein. I have to manually copy-paste it. What I want to avoid is the copy-pasting.

Comment: These commands prompt for a remote, not a branch. The push-remote is a remote. It can be configured per-branch using `branch.<branch>.pushRemote` or for all branches using `remote.pushDefault`. Git enforces that the "push remote branch" always has the same name as the local branch, you cannot use another name. If you have a single remote, then you can just accept the default using `RET`, otherwise you have to select a remove.

Comment: Indeed, doing `Pp` and replying "origin" (or whatever other remote name) works as desired! It does not set the branch for `Pu`, though, so following pushes need to be `Pp`s, too.